# Getting logged on user name at any Trac wiki page (Trac 0.11)

Tags: wiki, trac

When I create a report I can filter the results based on the logged on user name using the $USER magic variable. Is there any equivalent way to get the logged on user name at any Trac wiki page?

E.g.: The logged on user is [[User]].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you need a plugin to do it.  Nothing complex; just throw this:

```
from trac.wiki.macros import WikiMacroBase

class UserMacro(WikiMacroBase):
    def expand_macro(self, formatter, name, args):
        return formatter.req.authname;
```

Into a file like `<trac_env>/plugins/username.py` and add `[[User]]` to a wiki page.  For non-logged in users, it'll show `anonymous`.

Comment: @ing0: It's based on the name of the macro class.

Comment: Ah I see. So if you called the class HelloMacro, it would work with [[Hello]]?